# How to test/add data with associations in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a rails beginner and I'm having a little trouble testing model associations in the Rails Console. I know this is a simple fix, however, I'm not sure that I've created the appropriate models, or generated the right migrations, so I will include this information in this question.

I've read rails documentations (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html , http://api.rubyonrails.org/), I know the answer is in there, but i'm afraid my lack of experience is preventing me from totally maximizing the available documentation.

I need to be able to create an article that `has_many :categories, through: :article_categories` in the rails console

Here is the model for article , article_categories, and category

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :article_categories
has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
validates :title, presence: true
validates :content, presence: true
validates :categories, presence: true
  end

class ArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :article
belongs_to :category
 end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :article_categories
has_many :articles, through: :article_categories
validates :names, presence: true

 end
```

And here are the main migrations generated

```
Class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :articles do |t|
   t.string :title
   t.text :context
 end
end
```

end

```
class CreateArticleCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :article_categories do |t|
      t.belongs_to :article
      t.belongs_to :category
     t.timestamps
   end
  end
end

class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def change
      create_table :categories do |t|
       t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
 end
```

So, again, the question is if all models and migrations are appropriately generated. How would I go about testing it in the rails console by adding an `Article` that has a `Category`through the `ArticleCategories` table.

As of right new I've tested adding a new Category which works and adding an Article Category, which also works, but I do not know how to add the associations when I create an Article.

I've used

```
Article.errors.full_messages
```

which clearly tells me that I need to add categories before saving the article, but again, I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.build`

```
@article = Article.new(:title => "foo")
@category = @article.categories.build(:name => "bar")
@article.save
#@article & @category should now have been created
```

Or make them seperately and join them afterwards.

```
@article = Article.create(:title => "foo")
@category = Category.create(:name => "bar")
@article.categories << @category
```

Comment: I think you need to save the record after doing `@article.categories << @category` (not sure)

Comment: You don't, in my version of rails at least.

Comment: Max, this works to create associations, which is exactly what I was looking to do, however, i'm getting an error `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: article_id` when `INSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"` ..... Any Idea why?

Comment: Fixed! I needed to update the article_categories schema to include article_id and category_id columns.

Comment: Didn't the migrations you listed above do that?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought it was supposed to do, but when I checked schema.rb it only had the implicitly generated columns for "created_at" and "updated_at" so I generated a migration to add article_id & category_id to article categories and everything worked.

Comment: I must admit i've not seen this syntax used in migrations before `t.belongs_to :article`, so i assumed it was a "new rails" thing.

Answer (score -1):

`@article = Article.create(:title => "foo")`
`@article = Article.create(:title => "foo")`
`@article.categories << @category`